# matplotlib Axes3D error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the power generated by a wind turbine in function of the number of hours in a day and number of days in a year.

I made this small program :

```
wPower1 = np.zeros((365, 24))
d = np.mat(np.arange(24))
print d
y = np.mat(np.arange(365))
for heure in range(24):
    for jour in range(365):
        wPower1[jour][heure] = wPower[24 * (jour - 1) + heure]

print wPower1
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(d, y, wPower1, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

But I am getting this error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single
>   shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`plot_surface(X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) says

> `X,Y,Z` Data values as 2D arrays

In your case `d` and `y` are 1D. To create 2D arrays `numpy.meshgrid` is often useful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

wPower = np.random.rand(365*24)
wPower1 = wPower.reshape(365, 24)

d,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(24),np.arange(365))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(d, y, wPower1, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```